# Summary type Sum is not appropriate for column of type System.String error

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am getting this error whenever I try to run my project although the column isn't of type system.string. I have a page that is coded the same way with different numbers and it doesn't give me this error. This is my SQL string:

```
    MyCompSqlString = "SELECT (KAIPRDDTA.F4102LA.IBPRP6)ColOne, (KAIPRDCOM.F0005.DRDL01)ColTwo, COUNT(KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDSOQS*.01)ColThree, SUM(KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDAEXP*.01*CXCRR)ColFour, count(SDDOC)ColFive, SUM(KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDSOQS*.01)ColSix "
    MyCompSqlString += "FROM KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA, KAIPRDDTA.F55311, KAIPRDCOM.F0005, KAIPRDDTA.F0015, KAIPRDDTA.F4102LA"
    MyCompSqlString += "WHERE DRSY = '41' AND DRRT = '01' AND TRIM(DRKY) = IBPRP6 AND KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDITM = KAIPRDDTA.F4102LA.IBITM AND KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDMCU = KAIPRDDTA.F4102LA.IBMCU AND KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDSLSM = KAIPRDDTA.F55311.TERR AND (KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDIVD >= " & SDJ & ") AND (KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDIVD <= " & EDJ & ") AND "
    MyCompSqlString += "(KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDSLSM > 0) AND (KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDGLC NOT IN ('FT60', 'TXTX', 'IN20', 'INSP', 'INWC', 'INWR', 'INWS','',' ')) AND "
    MyCompSqlString += "(trim(KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDLNTY) NOT IN ('T', 'F', 'TX', 'TA', 'TS', 'RF', 'RP','BC')) AND (KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDNXTR <> '999') AND (KAIPRDDTA.F42119LA.SDDCTO not in ('ST','CR','SR')) "
    MyCompSqlString += "AND (KAIPRDDTA.F55311.VIEWID = '" & MyView & "') AND (SDAN8 <> 24157 and SDAN8 <> 152) AND ((SDTRDJ-1)=CXEFT) AND (SDBCRC=CXCRCD) AND (CXCRDC ='USD')"
    MyCompSqlString += "GROUP BY KAIPRDDTA.F4102LA.IBPRP6, KAIPRDCOM.F0005.DRDL01"
```

and this is my summary row:

```
  <ig:SummaryRow EmptyFooterText="" FormatString=" {1}" ShowSummariesButtons="false">
                <ColumnSummaries>
                    <ig:ColumnSummaryInfo ColumnKey="ColThree">
                        <Summaries>
                            <ig:Summary SummaryType="Sum" />
                        </Summaries>
                    </ig:ColumnSummaryInfo>
                    <ig:ColumnSummaryInfo ColumnKey="ColFour">
                        <Summaries>
                            <ig:Summary SummaryType="Sum" />
                        </Summaries>
                    </ig:ColumnSummaryInfo>
                    <ig:ColumnSummaryInfo ColumnKey="ColFive">
                        <Summaries>
                            <ig:Summary CustomSummaryName="100.00%" />
                        </Summaries>
                    </ig:ColumnSummaryInfo>
                    <ig:ColumnSummaryInfo ColumnKey="ColTwo">
                        <Summaries>
                            <ig:Summary CustomSummaryName="Totals:" />
                        </Summaries>
                    </ig:ColumnSummaryInfo>
                </ColumnSummaries>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it is giving me this error? Let me know if you need any more information and I will update my question. Thanks in advance for your responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a group which is `NULL`. This error means not all of the values are integer. So this query must produce a `NULL` as a value on some of the rows.

Comment: What would be your suggestion to fix this?

Comment: You have a `NULL` group because one of the two columns you make group by on has a `NULL` value in some row. In the end all `NULL` values are going into one group. What I can recommend is to execute the query without the group by and locate the rows where the aforementioned two columns are `NULL`. Restrict these rows, maybe by using `WHERE` clause. When you execute the query with the `GROUP BY` you shouldn't have a group with a `NULL` value.